# Flutter: Assertion failed error in ClipPath() widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I'm getting this error.

> ```
> Assertion failed: org-dartlang-sdk:///flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/surface/path/path_ref.dart:831:12
> isValid
> is not true
>
> The relevant error-causing widget was
>     ClipPath
> ```

The dependency I'm using is: `flutter_custom_clippers: ^1.1.1`

Whenever I restart or do a hot refresh, UI builds properly but after few seconds I get this error in the debug console.

The following is my widget structure.

```
ClipPath(
      clipper: WaveClipperTwo(flip: true, reverse: true),
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        width: double.infinity,
        height: 350,
        color: Colors.black87,
        child: ...
        )
);
```

How can I solve this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what actually happened, but I wrapped `ClipPath()` inside a container and gave it the height same as the Container inside it i.e. 350

> ```
> Container{
> height: 350,
> child: ClipPath(
>       clipper: WaveClipperTwo(flip: true, reverse: true),
>       child: Container(
>         padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
>         width: double.infinity,
>         height: 350,
>         color: Colors.black87,
>         child: ...
>         )
>     ),
> );
> ```

And then I didn't get any errors.

**I still don't know what that error was about, if you know Feel free to tell me :)**

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I had a similar error thrown by a container with a clipBehavior and borderRadius scrolling on Flutter web. No noticeable effects other than the error. I made the container a sized box and nested a ClipRRect inside it and the error goes away. Mysterious.